# Basic Cuda C++ project integration questions

Tags: c++, cuda

I’m very new to CUDA programming. I have an existing C++ project with some algorithms that can be split up into many mutually exclusive parts.

I have a few basic questions:

1. Can you write CUDA code in a .cpp file?
2. If no to 1 above, how to do you pass c++ object to a CUDA function?

Comment: I recommend asking 1 question per Question. It leads to more useful answers. I also recommend not asking question 3. requesting books and tutorials on Stack Overflow is forbidden because it has an annoying tendency to result in "My book is better than your book!" flame wars.

Comment: I don't understand how questions 1 and 2 are in any way connected to one another.  The answer to 1 is yes, but that in no way provides  information about whether question 2 is possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can answer 1. for you. Yes, you can write Cuda code in a .cpp file. You can read more about this [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/). It is mainly about the linking process. I hope that this helps you.